# jquery position() issues

Tags: jquery, position

I have a problem with jquery and `position()`.

I want to move a text element `<div id="text">` to sit onto another element on an event.
The other element looks like this:

```
<div id=pic><img src=pic.jpg></div>
```

The jquery i'm using to position it is this:

```
var pos = $('#pic').offset();
$('#text').animate({ top: pos.top, left: pos.left }, 0);
```

Now for some reason the #text is getting displayed way further over to the right and below the actual img div.

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: An example, like a jsFiddle, would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `#text` have `position: absolute` set? Animating the `top` and `left` properties won't have the expected effect otherwise. `.offset` returns the `top` and `left` relative to the document, but `.animate` modifies the `top` and `left` style properties, which are dependent upon the `position` property.